# Pyspark import .py file not working

Tags: python, apache-spark, python-import, pyspark

My goal is to import a custom .py file into my spark application and call some of the functions included inside that file

Here is what I tried:

I have a test file called ***Test.py*** which looks as follows:

```
def func():
    print "Import is working"
```

Inside my Spark application I do the following (as described in the docs):

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf, pyFiles=['/[AbsolutePathTo]/Test.py'])
```

I also tried this instead (after the Spark context is created):

```
sc.addFile("/[AbsolutePathTo]/Test.py")
```

I even tried the following when submitting my spark application:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.5.0-M2 --py-files /[AbsolutePath]/Test.py ../Main/Code/app.py
```

However, I always get a name error:

```
NameError: name 'func' is not defined
```

when I am calling ***func()*** inside my ***app.py***. (same error with 'Test' if I try to call ***Test.func()***)

Finally, al also tried importing the file inside the pyspark shell with the same command as above:

```
sc.addFile("/[AbsolutePathTo]/Test.py")
```

Strangely, I do not get an error on the import, but still, I cannot call func() without getting the error. Also, not sure if it matters, but I'm using spark locally on one machine.

I really tried everything I could think of, but still cannot get it to work. Probably I am missing something very simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the absolute path contain any space? Are you importing in the app.py file?

Comment: nope, no spaces in the path. Yes, app.py is my spark application where I'm trying to do the import. But as I said, I have the same Issue if I'm trying to do an import inside a pyspark shell.

Comment: How are you importing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "how", other than the 3 different approaches I tried and explained in the question?

Comment: I mean, in the file app.py, how do you import the file Test.py?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I thought that the addFile command actually imports the Test.py, so I didn't do any other import, which is why it didn't work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In case anybody will have the same issue in the future, I answered that question myself.

Comment: related to this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504849/pyspark-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o51-showstring-no-module-named-xxx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Alright, actually my question is rather stupid. After doing:

```
sc.addFile("/[AbsolutePathTo]/Test.py")
```

I still have to import the Test.py file like I would import a regular python file with:

```
import Test
```

then I can call

```
Test.func()
```

and it works. I thought that the "import Test" is not necessary since I add the file to the spark context, but apparently that does not have the same effect.
Thanks mark91 for pointing me into the right direction.

UPDATE 28.10.2017:

as asked in the comments, here more details on the app.py

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[4]")
conf.setAppName("Spark Stream")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.addFile("Test.py")

import Test

Test.func()
```

Comment: I am looking for something similar to this. Can you please post the full code (app.py) , how you are importing and calling test.func() please?