# Not able to access class methods from pyspark RDD's map method

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

While integrating pyspark in my application's code-base, I couldn't refer a class's method in a RDD's map method. I duplicated the issue with a simple example which is as follows

Here's a dummy class that, I have defined which just adds a number to every element of RDD derived from a RDD which is a class attribute:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = SparkContext()
        a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
        self.a_r = self.sc.parallelize(a)

    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def test_func(self, b):
        c_r = self.a_r.map(lambda l: (l[0], l[1] * 2))
        v = c_r.map(lambda l: self.add(l[1], b))
        v_c = v.collect()
        return v_c
```

`test_func()` calls `map()` method on a RDD `v`, which in-turn calls the `add()` method on every element of `v`. Calling `test_func()` throws the following error:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Now, when I move the `add()` method out of class like:

```
def add(self, a, b):
    return a + b

class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sc = SparkContext()
        a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
        self.a_r = self.sc.parallelize(a)

    def test_func(self, b):

        c_r = self.a_r.map(lambda l: (l[0], l[1] * 2))
        v = c_r.map(lambda l: add(l[1], b))
        v_c = v.collect()

        return v_c
```

Calling `test_func()` works properly now.

```
[7, 9, 11]
```

Why does it happen and how can I pass class methods to a RDD's `map()` method?

Answer (score 8):

This happens because when pyspark tries to serialize your function (to send it to workers), it needs to also serialize the instance of your `Test` class (because the function you're passing to `map` has a reference to this instance in `self`). This instance has a reference to the spark context. You need to make sure that `SparkContext` and `RDD`s are not referenced by any object that is serialized and sent to workers. `SparkContext` needs to live only in the driver.

This should work:

### In file `testspark.py`:

```py
class Test(object):
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

    def test_func(self, a_r, b):
        c_r = a_r.map(lambda l: (l[0], l[1] * 2))
        # now `self` has no reference to the SparkContext()
        v = c_r.map(lambda l: self.add(l[1], b)) 
        v_c = v.collect()
        return v_c
```

### In your main script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from testspark import Test

sc = SparkContext()
a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
a_r = sc.parallelize(a)

test = Test()
test.test_func(a_r, 5) # should give [7, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Does this actually work in passing methods to workers?  If your class is defined in the python kernel, yes, but if you are trying to access a module ( a .py) you'll have to use `.addPyfiles` as `import`ing to kernel won't work ([so ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532083/pyspark-import-user-defined-module-or-py-files)).

Comment: @ohailolcat That's a good point. In this answer I'm assuming that the python environment in the workers is the same as that in the driver (i.e: `testspark.py` is deployed to workers and it's in the `PYTHONPATH`) Otherwise `testspark.py` will need to be included through `.addPyfiles`