# numpy issue when doing spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

when i am submitting python script with spark-submit on my standalone ec2 spark cluster.
i use python 2.7.9 , validated that no other python is running in cluster.
 - i get the following error :

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

i validated that numpy is working on each of the workers with

```
root@10:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages# python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

also copied manually numpy package to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
but problem persists .

***update***
issue solved not according to the answer here .
the issue was that jupyter & numpy were installed on 1 docker image on the master , and the program ran on another image without numpy installation with the python in it .
so the solution was to install it as part of the docker image of the program and set the environment variables of PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYTHONPATH in it .

Comment: Can you import `numpy` on the driver as well ?

Comment: yes:


root@ip-10-0-5-253:/usr/spark-2.3.0# python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>

Comment: update - 
it works from jupyter notebook , that is installed on the master, and works against the cluster .
checked with :
    import numpy
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import PrefixSpan

data = [[["a", "b"], ["c"]],[["a"], ["c", "b"], ["a", "b"]],[["a", "b"], ["e"]],[["f"]]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
model = PrefixSpan.train(rdd, minSupport=0.1)
result = model.freqSequences().filter(lambda x: (x.freq >= 2)).filter(lambda x: (len(x.sequence) >=2) ).cache()
result.collect()

spark-submit still fails ...... :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark import user defined module or .py files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532083/pyspark-import-user-defined-module-or-py-files)

Comment: i am running in cluster mode , so i don't see it is related