# PySpark ImportError: No module named although included in --pyfiles

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run a PySpark application. the spark submit command looks something like this.

```
spark-submit --py-files /some/location/data.py /path/to/the/main/file/etl.py
```

My main file(etl.py) imports the data.py and uses the functions from data.py file, the code looks like this.

```
    import data
    def main(args_dict):
        print(args_dict)
        df1 = data.get_df1(args_dict['df1name'])
        df1 = data.get_df2(args_dict['df1name'])
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

I'm passing the data.py file in the --py-files, but when I run the spark-submit I'm getting `ImportError: No module named 'data'`
I'm trying to figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share some code please? try this `from data import *`.

Comment: Please look at the above edit. @karma4917

Comment: Did you try `from data import *`

Comment: Yeah...tried that too..but got the same error.

Comment: Try zipping that file and try again.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532084/8085047 .. add sc.addFile() in your spark job.