# PySpark: An error occurred while calling o51.showString. No module named XXX

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My pyspark version is 2.2.0. I came to a strange problem. I try to simplify it as the following. The files structure:

```
|root
|-- cast_to_float.py
|-- tests
    |-- test.py
```

In `cast_to_float.py`, my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def cast_to_float(y, column_name):
    return y.withColumn(column_name, y[column_name].cast(FloatType()))

def cast_to_float_1(y, column_name):
    to_float = udf(cast2float1, FloatType())
    return y.withColumn(column_name, to_float(column_name))

def cast2float1(a):
    return 1.0
```

In `test.py`:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
import sys
parentPath = os.path.abspath('..')
if parentPath not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, parentPath)

from cast_to_float import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("tests").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([
            (1, 1),
            (2, 2),
            (3, 3),
        ], ["ID", "VALUE"])
df1 = cast_to_float(df, 'ID')
df2 = cast_to_float_1(df, 'ID')

df1.show()
df1.printSchema()
df2.printSchema()
df2.show()
```

Then I run the test in tests folder, I get the error message, which is from the last line, saying:

```
+---+-----+
| ID|VALUE|
+---+-----+
|1.0|    1|
|2.0|    2|
|3.0|    3|
+---+-----+

root
 |-- ID: float (nullable = true)
 |-- VALUE: long (nullable = true)

root
 |-- ID: float (nullable = true)
 |-- VALUE: long (nullable = true)

    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-86eb5df2f917> in <module>()
     19 df1.printSchema()
     20 df2.printSchema()
---> 21 df2.show()
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o257.showString.
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cast_to_float'
...
```

It seems the `cast_to_float` is imported, otherwise, I cannot get `df1` even.

If I put `test.py` in the same directory of `cast_to_float.py`, and run it in that directory, then it's OK. Any ideas? Thanks!

---

I used @user8371915 `__file__` method, and found it's OK if I ran it in `root` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is right now, the result will depend on the working directory, where you invoke the script.

If you're in root, this will add its parent. You should use path relative to `__file__` (see [what does the __file__ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9271464)):

```
parentPath = os.path.join(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 
    os.path.pardir
)
```

but I'd will recommend using proper package structure.

**Note**:

This covers only local mode and driver path and even in local mode, worker paths, are not affected by the driver path.

To handle executor paths (after changes you get executor exceptions) you should still distribute modules to the workers [How to use custom classes with Apache Spark (pyspark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31093179/8371915).

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("tests").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("/path/to/cast_to_float.py")
```